# Pull ssh keys in docker container at runtime

Tags: node.js, git, ssh, docker, dockerfile

I am creating a nodejs application that will integrate with Git repo and perform operations such as push, pull commit etc. I am in the process of moving the app to Docker. 
However I can't find a way to put ssh keys in the docker image at runtime. I want to avoid copying the ssh key at build time in the docker image for security reasons.

I have tried passing the ssh key as an env variable at runtime like :

```
docker run -i -t -e KEY="sshkey" imagename
```

And in node.js manually creating the ssh folder and ssh key

```
mkdirSync('/root/.ssh/', (err) => {
    writeFileSync('/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', sshKey, (err) => {
    })
})
```

However this doesn't seem to be working, I still get permission errors when trying to clone the repo.

1. Do I need to do something to load the ssh keys so they can be used by git?
2. Is there a way to do it using Dockerfile. I know that I can add it on build, time, but haven't found a way to do it at runtime.
3. How can I inspect the fs of a running docker container?

Comment: Can't you just do a volume/file mount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to add your **private** key if you want to authenticate via SSH, not your public key. In your case, that's probably the file `id_rsa`. The public key is used by the server to verify your identity.
2. The `Dockerfile` is only used for the build, so there is no way to use it to do anything at runtime. I think your approach with the environment variable is reasonable...
3. You can connect to the container via `docker exec`, open the bash and interact with the filesystem like you normally would:

   ```
   docker exec -it imagename /bin/bash
   ```

   This assumes that you are running a system with a bash. Otherwise, try `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Thanks for that, using env variables and the private key worked. A couple of things that I had to solve in case anyone else tries it: 1. create the key file using the Dockerfile 2.give the correct permissions to the file so you can write from your node.js app

Answer (score 2):

The following contrived example demonstrates how a private key on the host machine can be read from within a container.

```
docker run -it --rm -v ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa:ro ubuntu cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This should let a process running as root authenticate with your credential.

Answer (score 0):

For non root user at host and docker:

```
docker run -v /home/<host user>/.ssh:/home/<docker user>/.ssh <image>
```